# Can chrome extensions be used for patching browser compatibility issues?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a legacy application which at the time only works on Internet Explorer. It doesn't work with chrome or any another application. The reason for that is that it uses **ActiveXObject** extensively. Since **ActiveXObject** is not available in non-IE browsers, the application fails to render. 
I was wondering if a chrome extension can be developed which can patch the script upon page load and then again bootstrap the javascript only.
I tried a lot of google search to come up with a decent explanation with no luck.
Anyone here has any experience with developing chrome extensions? Can my idea be implemented?

Comment: if chrome natively doesn't support activeX, then you cannot use it even with chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so- in general, the Javascript code in your extension can not interact directly with Javascript code on the page, so you couldn't directly modify it so it doesn't use ActiveX if that is your plan. They share a DOM, but not an execution environment. Have a look at the documentation : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

Chrome doesn't support ActiveX anyway, so that limits you a lot too. In your case, the better option is probably to rewrite the legacy application to not use ActiveX, if that is possible.

Comment: its true that is not possible but the reasons are incorrect. an extension CAN share the same execution environment by injecting a script.

Comment: Ah, you're right- a content script won't work, but you can inject a script tag to some resource that patches the legacy code. That's a good point actually, it's a little messy but it does work, I have even done it myself because it's needed for [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/)...hmm. But I think in this particular case it makes more sense to just rewrite the legacy app since that's an option.